# Fb profile pic not coming with a better quality

Tags: android

I have used the following code, able to get the image but when I am trying to put it on Layout background(Linear Layout), the image quality gets reduced and it shows a blurred image.

```
URL img_value = null;

    try {
        img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userId+"/picture?type=large");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt=new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
        opt.inSampleSize=1;
        // mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathoffile,opt);

        mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream(),null,opt);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(mIcon1);
    ll.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to set that image to the background of a LinearLayout. I am going to assume that this background is roughly the size of the phone's screen.

I just tried out that facebook URL and the size of the image I am getting back is 180x195.

Considering the smallest Android screen I am aware of is 240x320, that image will have to be blown up on every single Android phone. This will cause the image to look blurry, as the resolution of the image is much lower than that of Android screens.

I recommend you find higher resolution images for your backgrounds.

Comment: I am using graph API here and it has limitations like the size of image can be small,large,medium.Is there any other way to achieve it apart from Graph API

Comment: Not with that API call. There are others you can play around with though. Photos, for example, are usually larger, but it is more difficult to figure out how to get the photo you want.